# Dynamically UIButton action inside container on scrollview not working

Tags: swift, uiview, uiscrollview, uibutton

Im having some issues with action of UIButtons inside a custom hierarchy of UIViews, this views, are inside a container on a scrollview
Depending on my need, ill create or not the buttons..
If i try to create the same button, but on self.view, it work perfectly.

the hierarchy is this:

```
    - UIScrollView
      - UIView (scroll content) //all above are dynamically created
        - UIView (dynamically)
          - UIButton (dynamically)
        - UIView (dynamically)
           - UIButton (dynamically)
```

im trying this way to create the view:

```
    class ScrollViewController: UIViewController {
       @IBOutlet weak var scrollContent: UIView!

       func createViews() {
         let containerButton = UIView()
         self.scrollContent.addSubview(containerButton)
         containerButton.autoPinEdge(toSuperviewEdge: .top, withInset: 16)
         containerButton.autoPinEdge(toSuperviewEdge: .left, withInset: 16)
         containerButton.autoPinEdge(toSuperviewEdge: .right, withInset: 16)
         containerButton.autoSetDimension(.height, toSize: 200)

         let button = UIButton()
         containerButton.addSubview(button)
         button.autoPinEdge(toSuperviewEdge: .top, withInset: 8)
         button.autoPinEdge(toSuperviewEdge: .left, withInset: 8)
         button.autoPinEdge(toSuperviewEdge: .right, withInset: 8)

         button.addTargetClosure { _ in
            print("button tapped")
         }
       } 
    }
```

all views are added perfectly, but the action of buttons dont work.

im using PureLayout for constraints..

if i add

```
    button.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: containerButton.centerYAnchor).isActive = true
```

it seens to work, but mess with my layout..

im using this format to add targets on buttons

https://medium.com/@jackywangdeveloper/swift-the-right-way-to-add-target-in-uibutton-in-using-closures-877557ed9455

i dont know if im missing something or doing something wrong on creating the views. What i have to do to make buttons actions work inside a container in scrollview content?

Thank you!

Comment: Try this: containerButton.isUserInteractionEnabled = true. This issue might be about the view's userInteraction is false by default.

Comment: Hello! add this, still dont work :(

Comment: Can you edit your code and show me how you add your targets for buttons?

Comment: Have You tried setting constraints on width and height for button?

Comment: We need to see all the code, perhaps the button is covered by some other view, can't tell now. Try containerButton.clipsToBounds = true and see if the button still remains visible. In addition, there is a button in Xcode for debugging UI, and check the view hierarchy and frames for all views. See here how to do it https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KUjbhGOV7DM

Comment: Edited with full code, still dont work with clipsToBounds..

Answer (score 0):

Try creating the view, setting view's `userInteractionEnabled` to `true` and button. Then add button to the view, after that add view to the container view of scrollView:

```
func createViews() {
     //creating the container
     let containerButton = UIView()
     containerButton.isUserInteractionEnabled = true

     //creating the button
     let button = UIButton()
     self.containerButton.addSubview(button)

     // add view to scrollContent now.
     self.scrollContent.addSubview(containerButton)
   }
```